# Spring REST API Response for Junction Tables

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I have a MySQL DB and a SpringBoot application running on Tomcat.  This is a personal project of mine and my first experience designing REST services.  I have been trying to create my POJOs to match the database, but this particular object is creating some doubts.

Here are the primary database tables:

- player (id, description)
- campaign (id, description)
- resource (id, description, resource_type_id)
- resource_type (id, description)
- component (id, description)

...and following junction tables:

- player_resource (id, player_id, resource_id): a player may have many resources, and a resource may belong to many players.
- campaign_resource (id, campaign_id, resource_id): a campaign may have many resources and a resource may belong to many campaigns.
- resource_component (id, resource_id, component_id): a resource may have many components and a component may belong to many resources

I'm sort of lost on how I should be designing my JSON response and the corresponding POJO(s) for the Resource object specifically.

What I'm thinking so far is to have three separate URI:

1. **.../api/resources/{uuid}**: Returns the specific Resource.
2. **.../api/campaigns/{uuid}/resources**: Returns which resources are available in the supplied campaign.  As an aside, players exist within the scope of a campaign so this particular API ultimately determines what's available to a player to obtain in the course of their existence.
3. **.../api/players/{uuid}/resources**: Returns which resources the player currently has in their inventory.

I created a single POJO for Resource:

```
public class Resource {

    private String resourceId;
    private String shortDescription;
    private String longDescription;
    private ResourceType resourceType;
    private List<Component> components;

    // getters and setters

}
```

I created two additional POJOs for CampaignResource and PlayerResource:

```
public class CampaignResource {

    private String campaignResourceId;
    private Resource resource;

    // getters and setters

}

public class PlayerResource {

    private String playerResourceId;
    private Resource resource;

    // getters and setters

}
```

I expect URI #1 and #2 to return the same layout, but I have redundancy concerns with URI #3.  URI #2 may return ten Resources which is fine and expected, but URI #3 could return hundreds depending on what a player is carrying around.

The only information I really need when calling URI #3 are the player_resource_id, resource_id, and resource_type_id fields.  I do not need to know what components comprise a resource because that information is brought back in a much more manageable fashion using either URI #1 or URI #1.

I'm afraid to create separate "base" Resource POJOs since I feel obligated to follow some form of canonical modeling.  Could I use something like a JsonView and separate Resource RowMappers based on whether it's URI #1, #2, or #3?  I could implement some form of paging, but it's still a lot of redundant data.  How would a veteran REST developer approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to create separate classes that contain resource for each REST API. Just return one Resource for #1 and list of Resource(s) for #2 and #3.

Comment: That won't work for my .../api/players/{uuid}/resources call because I need to return the playerResourceId field which contains the junction key for the player_resource table.  A player can have many of the same resource so without playerResourceId I could not identify a unique instance of Resource.

Comment: Your rest call contract says to return resources for a given player identified by its UUID. The caller should not care about playerResourceId. By exposing playerResourceId you are spilling your database design to the external caller. What if later you decide to not use junction table for your player to resource association but normalize and put resource UUID in players table, what playerResourceId are you going to return?

Comment: There would still need to be a key to identify the specific instance of a Resource.  Example, if I have a resource 'Wood' and my player has two 'Wood' resources - I need to use something to differentiate the two.  Is there a better way than using a UUID?

Comment: Your resource has "resourceId" field. Is not it a unique identifier? If not, maybe you need to make it unique.

Comment: It uniquely identifies a type of resource - not a specific instance of a resource.  I could probably better describe the 'player_resource' table instead as the 'inventory' table, change 'player_resource_id' to 'inventory_id', and it would make more sense.  I feel that's more semantic though, but maybe for the customer-facing side it makes sense that way?

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you want to know about RESTful API's [this post](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api) will help a lot. Specifically about what you are asking, look in the topic *Limiting which fields are returned by the API*:

> Use a fields query parameter that takes a comma separated list of fields to include.

For Example:

`GET /tickets?fields=id,subject,customer_name,updated_at&state=open&sort=-updated_at`

[Here](https://apigee.com/about/blog/technology/restful-api-design-can-your-api-give-developers-just-information-they-need) you can find how Google, Facebook and LinkdIn do.

[]s

Comment: I'm not sure it makes sense to add a fields filter.  I wouldn't want to add campaignResourceId or playerResourceId to the base Resource class because those fields aren't always present.  Allowing the consumer to request them would result in an error.